# Under what assumptions on f can I calculate f([a, b])?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, interval-arithmetic

I know that:

- If $f$ is continuous and monotonous on $[a, b]$, then $$f([a, b]) = [\min(f(a), f(b)), \max(f(a), f(b))]$$
- If $f$ is continuous and unimodal on $[a, b]$ with an extremum at $x_0 \in [a, b]$, then $$f([a, b]) = [\min\{f(a), f(x_0), f(b)\}, \max\{f(a), f(x_0), f(b)\}]$$
- If $f=\cos$ or $f=\sin$, then I can calculate $f([a, b])$ with a tedious disjunction of six cases depending on the positions of $a$ and $b$ relative to $2k\pi$ and $(2k+1)\pi$.
- If $f$ is periodic with period $T$ and $b-a \geq T$, then $f([a, b]) = \operatorname{range}(f)$; but if $b-a < T$, not much can be said.

**What other assumption on $f$ could allow me to calculate $f([a, b])$?**

By "calculate" I mean constructively calculate, assuming that I can call function $f$ on particular values, including $a$, $b$, any value given as part of the assumption such as $x_0$ above, and any other value that I can constructively calculate.

Comment: @J.Dmaths I'm not sure I follow. If $f$ has jump discontinuities then the jumps might be reflected in the image. If $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$ for instance, then $f$ is increasing, and bounded on any bounded interval, but $f([0, 2]) = \{0, 1, 2\} \neq [f(0), f(2)]$

Comment: Yes, you're right, it doesn't necessarily attain every value in the range! My bad.

Comment: @J.Dmaths Although you are right in the sense that if $f$ is monotonous on $[a, b]$ then I can always write $f([a, b]) \subseteq [\min\{f(a), f(b)\}, \max\{f(a), f(b)\}]$, but I'm hoping to write exact sets rather than supersets.

Comment: Define "calculate." E.g. do you accept, say, $f$ continuous implying $f([a, b]) = [\min_{a \leq x \leq b} f(x), \max_{a \leq x \leq b} f(x)]$?

Comment: @BenSteffan Maybe I should say "constructively calculate"? Your equation is true but the question is how to find these minimum and maximum? Assuming I can call $f$ on particular values, including $a$, $b$, any other value I can construct and any value given in assumption (such as the location $x_0$ of the extremum in the unimodal assumption in my post)

Comment: @Stef Thanks for clarifying. Perhaps you should include that in your question :)

Comment: BenSteffan's comment is the gold standard for continuous functions. The only question is "can you find the maximum and minimum of $f$ on $[a,b]$"? If the answer is yes, then he gives the interval. If the answer is no, then no, you cannot calculate the interval as its endpoints are the maximum and minimum that you cannot find.